# Extract Pydantic ValidationError message

Tags: python, json, pydantic, validationerror

How do I extract just the `msg` value from a Pydantic `ValidationError` object?

I tried with:

```py
json.loads(ValidationError_obj.json()[]['msg'])
```

But I am trying to find some simple built-in method.

Comment: the `[]` in `obj.json()[]['msg']` makes no sense

Comment: src definition of `ValidationError` is here: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.5/pydantic/error_wrappers.py#L50 might help

Answer (score 2):

`ValidationError.json` returns a **string** in JSON format. That is not what you want.

The `ValidationError.errors` method returns a list of dictionaries, wherein each dictionary represents one of the errors accumulated in the `ValidationError`.

Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError


class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar: int
    baz: str


try:
    Foo.parse_obj({"bar": "definitely not an integer"})
except ValidationError as exc:
    print(exc.errors())
```

Output: (formatted for readability)

```py
[
  {'loc': ('bar',), 'msg': 'value is not a valid integer', 'type': 'type_error.integer'},
  {'loc': ('baz',), 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}
]
```

As you can see in this example, when there is more than one error, there will be more than one dictionary, each with its own `msg` key.

If you are only interested in the first (or you know for a fact that there will be only one specific error), you can just do this:

```py
...

try:
    Foo.parse_obj({"bar": "definitely not an integer"})
except ValidationError as exc:
    print(exc.errors()[0]["msg"])
```

Output: `value is not a valid integer`